# Detecting OpenGL ES in LibGDX to adjust shader code accordingly

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a LibGDX app that runs on mobile and desktop systems just fine except for one tiny issue:

On mobile devices I need to include precision qualifiers in my shaders (`precision highp float`), but on Mac OS this leads to an error when I compile the shader since precision qualifiers technically only exist on OpenGL ES (although Windows just ignores them).

Is there a way in LibGDX to determine whether I am running under OpenGL ES or under regular OpenGL so I can adjust my shader code accordingly? Other than the obvious super-inelegant solution, of course: Try to compile the shader with the qualifiers, if it fails try again without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use preprocessing directives at the top of your fragment shader.

```
#ifdef GL_ES 
precision highp float;
#endif
```

You can also use placeholders so you can adjust precision of specific variables.

```
#ifdef GL_ES 
#define LOWP lowp
#define MEDP mediump
#define HIGHP highp
precision highp float;
#else
#define LOWP
#define MEDP
#define HIGHP
#endif
```

Then you can use the text `LOWP` in place of `lowp` and it will evaluate blank on desktop:

```
varying LOWP vec4 v_color;
```

Comment: That's an awesome solution! Thanks! No need even to adjust my shader code dynamically!

Comment: Wow I did not know you can use ifdef GL_ES, this is way more elegant than what I am doing in my project... (searching for substrings in GL_VERSION string reported from implementation...)